# Who is Robert H. Cowen, the eponym of Cowen's Lemma?

Tags: biographical-details

Context: I have arrived at Section $7$ of chapter $4$ of Smullyan and Fitting's *Set Theory and the Continuum Problem* during my ongoing self-study odyssey.

This section raises and proves **Cowen's theorem** but gives no historical background apart from providing the citation:

> Cowen, R.H. (1971), 'Superinductive classes in class-set theory', *Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic* **12**(1) 62-68

Checking this out, we have **Robert H. Cowen** who reports as being a student of Ray Smullyan at the time he wrote it (1969).

From what I can tell, he is **not** the same Cowen as the eponym of the Cowen-Thomson Theorem, as that one seems to be attributed to **C. Cowen**.

However, he probably **is** the eponym of the Cowen-Engeler Lemma

Apart from other papers attributed to Robert Cowen in the same field of study, I have been unable to find any biographical details for him: birth date, birthplace, nationality (American assumed), etc.

Anyone out there able to help?

Comment: There is a very very short biographical notice in "Raymond Smullyan on Self Reference", here shorturl.at/bcAMT at page 19

Comment: Hmm ... it doesn't give much away, but it's useful up to a point. Thx.

Comment: He worked at Queens College, CUNY, for 40 years and retired in 2008, now emeritus. He had a [blog](https://www.blogger.com/profile/02827732126659424207) with contact information and an [autobiographical post](http://rcowen.blogspot.com/2013/01/robert-cowen-my-first-years-at-queens.html). His webpage is expired, but Wayback Machine saved a [snapshot from 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20151004014312/https://sites.google.com/site/robertcowen/). [List of publications](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Robert-Cowen-2) up to May 2022.

Comment: @Conifold Thank you for finding that, it had eluded me.

Comment: Jason Rosenhouse (ed.), "Four Lives -- A Celebration of Raymond Smullyan", 2014, [p. 139](https://books.google.com/books?id=e1nLAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&#v=onepage&q&f=false): *Robert Cowen received his AB from Princeton in 1961. It was during this time at Princeton that he first met Raymond Smullyan. He received his PhD in mathematics from Yeshiva University in 1967.* From other sources you already know that Smullyan was Cowen's PhD advisor at Yeshiva University. Data from public records aggregation companies available online for free *suggests* that Robert Cowen was born in 1941.

Comment: I was guessing 1943 on the grounds that his retirement announcement on 31 Jan 2008 was when he was 65. But 1941 is equally plausible. Mind, if he was at Queens in Sept 1966 from which he never left for 42 years, what was he doing at Yeshiva in 1967? I'm confused. Unless the bestowal of the PhD was several months after completing his Yeshiva attachment and leaving to go to Queens.

Comment: @PrimeMover The data from the public record aggregators seems plausible, stating his birth year as 1941 and his wife Ilsa's as 1943. The personal data in the book by Rosenhouse was presumably furnished by the contributors themselves. Also, the [Math Genealogy page for Cowen](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=105327) says PhD in 1967 at Yeshiva University advised by Smullyan. The AB Princeton in 1961 (at presumed age of 20) seems plausible given that his daughter [Leonore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenore_Cowen) (math professor at Tuft) entered Yale at age 16.

Comment: @PrimeMover A 2007 [letter to the editor](https://www.princeton.edu/~paw/archive_new/PAW06-07/08-0214/letters.html) of the Princeton Alumni Weekly confirms Cowen's graduation in 1961: *It seems to me that you are, for the most part, covering those Princetonians who are involved in making war in Iraq. How about some articles on those of us who are actively opposing this war and feel that doing so truly expresses “Princeton in the nation’s service”? ROBERT COWEN ’61 Queens, N.Y.*

Comment: "News and Notices", *The American Mathematical Monthly*, Vol. 84, No. 4, Apr. 1977, pp. 312-314 *Queens College-CUNY: Assistant Professor Robert Cowen has been promoted to Associate Professor*

Comment: From Robert Cowen's [blog](http://rcowen.blogspot.com/2013/01/robert-cowen-my-first-years-at-queens.html): *"I retired from the Math Department in 2008 after teaching for over 40 years. I came to Queens College in September of 1966 as a lecturer in the Mathematics Department."* In Robert H. Cowen, "Superinductive classes in class-set theory," *Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic*, Vol. 12, No. 1, January 1971, pp. 62-68, Cowen cites his PhD thesis as follows: Cowen, R. H., *Superinductive Classes and Constructible Models of Set Theory* (PhD thesis), Yeshiva University (1967).

Comment: [Kochaviah 1966](https://archive.org/details/kochaviah1966stern0), Yearbook, Stern College for Women, Yeshiva University, p. 10: "Faculty [...] Robert H. Cowen, B.A., M.A., Lecturer in Mathematics"

Comment: J.W. Green and E. Pitcher, "The April Meeting in New York", *Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society*, Vol. 71, No. 4, July 1965, pp. 589-599 : "The six hundred twenty-second meeting of the American Mathematical Society was held at the Waldorf-Astoria in New York on April 12-15, 1965. [...] The following three hundred seventy-two persons have been elected to membership in the Society on nomination of institutional members as indicated: [...] *Yeshiva University*: Elliott Beller, Robert H. Cowen, Dévora M. Kasachkloff [...]"